# Selenium liveServerTestCase is using Test Database instead of Project database (Django)

Tags: selenium, django-models, pytest, django-contrib, liveservertestcase

I am beginning to try Django testing using selenium , I am following this tutorial
[Selenium | Django | Gentle Introduction, Setup and Start Testing](https://youtu.be/XnSQ6sRGKzI?t=1211)

while trying to run a simple login test case i am getting in the test browser:

> username and password do not match

i think it is because the test case is not getting access to project database and instead is using test database.**Can someone also guide me regarding whether the LiveServerTestCase uses Project Database or separate Test Database.**

for login i am using authentication utility provided by `django.contrib.auth.urls`

**test.py**

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


class LoginFormTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def testform(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/mueezkhan/django-test/chromedriver")

        driver.get(self.live_server_url + '/accounts/login/')
        time.sleep(3)
        user_name = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
        user_password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
        time.sleep(3)
        submit = driver.find_element_by_id('submit')

        

        
        user_name.send_keys('admin')
        user_password.send_keys('admin')

        submit.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        assert 'admin' in driver.page_source
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for test_basic project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-skk*&_lt6r^t+aud^8vg(gc6)ayx5nvrwco^v-m)1nk&_1-)tl'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'test_basic.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'test_basic.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Comment: _...test case is not getting access to project database and instead is using test database..._: How can [_Selenium_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) help here?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium maybe it is happening because i configured selenium incorrectly and someone could guide me in the right direction.